# Implement an instant search functionality

Tags: javascript

I want to implement a functionality in my wikipedia app which gives the user two options:

- An option to do an instant search, i.e. get results as the user types in the search box
- An option to do a normal serach upon hitting `Enter`. i have a button to toggle that functionality.

Below is the JS code:

```
var btn = $(".autocomplete-button .btn")
btn.click(searchOptions);

function searchOptions() {

    btn.html() === "Instant Results Off" ?
        btn.html("Instant Results On") :
        btn.html("Instant Results Off");

    if (btn.html() === "Instant Results On") {
        advancedSearch();
        onSubmit();
    } else {
        onSubmit();
    }
};

function advancedSearch() {

    $("#wiki-search").keyup(function (e) {
        getArticles();
    });
}

onSubmit();

function onSubmit() {

    $(".search-form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        getArticles();
    });
}
```

You can test out the app here: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/binarytrance/pen/xOBdrv)

**Problem:** The default search method is a normal search. Once i turn the `instant search on`the app always does an instant search no matter what the current setting is.

**What have i tried?** i assumed the `advancedSearch` function keeps running regardless of what setting the button displays. Therefore i included a conditional to `return` the function whenever the button is clicked. But that didn't solve anything.

Please note the console messages. the console.log statements that i have placed in each function clearly convey that the `advancedSearch` function is correctly not being triggered when the instant search button is set to off and thats what makes this behavior so puzzling to me.

any solutions to this problem will be appreciated. I will change the title of the qn once the reason of the problem will be known. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a switch variable like this:

```
var liveSearchSwitch = 0;
```

and, make some simple logic changes.

OK, I made it:

https://codepen.io/mgolshan/pen/BLBEdR

You can see the difference with JavaScript code and mine here:

https://www.diffnow.com/?report=25eyh

Please let me know if you couldn't get what I did

Comment: thanks. works great. in my original code, the function advancedSearch() didnt get triggered when instant search was turned off. why then does adding the conditional `if (liveSearchSwitch) {
        getArticles();
      }` inside that function fix the issue?

Comment: @snow Cool. glad to hear that

Comment: if you don't mind, my comment has a question about what i didn't get about your changes

Comment: @snow, you have a keyup event listener. you need a logic to know in which case you should fire the getArticles() on keyup. When, your setting is off, it should not call the function getArticles()